# Will this application tree be garbage collected?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, clr

In my app composition root a large instance tree is built where parent nodes can be implicitly referenced by child nodes through for instance delegates and observers. This is a simplified view of the managed objects' relationships:

```
A    <---+
  B    | |
  C  - + |
  D      |
E        | <-+
  F  ----+   |
  G          |
    I -------+
```

My hunch is that if I in my composition root have references to objects A and E and then set those to null, the complete object tree will be garbage collected.

Correct?

Comment: "have references to objects A and B" - shouldn't that be A and E ?

Comment: @Henk: Yes - thanks for the catch! Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct, given that you don't have any other *reachable* references to nodes in the tree. This is because unreachable objects referencing each other are *still* eligible for garbage collection if there are no external (i.e. reachable) references to any of them.

Comment: What about F --> A? I'm not sure exactly if I understand the question correctly, but isn't the whole thing in the end a group of objects referring to each other? Please elaborate more if my question makes no sense...

Comment: Yes, it's a group of objects referring to each other. These are eligible for garbage collection if there are no external references to any of them, i.e. if they are not reachable. This is because the garbage collector uses swipe algorithms instead of reference counting algorithms.

Comment: I get your point. Just to make sure, F has nothing referring to it, right? Or another unreachable object(s) are referring to it...

Comment: another unreachable objects can be referring to it - that doesn't prevent from garbage collection

Comment: That's what I meant, thank you for clariying more. I meant "either F has nothing referring to it, or it *does* have references to it but from *unreachable* objects".

Comment: @Petar: Sorry for in initial typo. I wrote **B** instead of **E**. I meant *... references to objects A and E and then ...*. But I think your answer reflects what I actually meant, not what I wrote.